# How can I set up Atlassian JIRA Core in a Docker container in my Ubuntu's machine on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

I trying to set up Atlassian JIRA Core in a Docker container... here is link 
https://hub.docker.com/r/cptactionhank/atlassian-jira/ on my machine Ubuntu 18.04 on Google Cloud... However I have not had result

My Docker version -> 18.09.7

First Step -> I had set up rules of firewall on Google Cloud. Then I added these in protocols and ports

tcp:8081
tcp:9999
tcp:8080
tcp:8090

After I set up this .... and Finally I excecuted highlights on ubuntu shell

## Shell Ubuntu

Yesterday I executed the following container on different ports and I had not response

That another setting up I should make... Maybe in Google Cloud, Ubuntu or Docker....

Comment: Full disclosure, I work for Atlassian. I'd recommend you use our official Docker image for Jira: https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/jira-core , it allows for much more from-the-environment configuration in the style of most containerised applications.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could solve that by excecution this command 
**sudo ufw allow 8090/tcp**

Reference :

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/STXKQY_5.0.3/com.ibm.spectrum.scale.v5r03.doc/bl1adv_firewallportopenexamples.htm